# CSS - Style a Website by its Structure and not with a ton of classes

Tags: html, css

I'm currently writing a small website for fun and
now I need to design it and I'm not really experienced in CSS.
I don't want to declare a ton of classes or ids in my html file, so my question is if there is a way to avoid these within the CSS code.

Wasn't there a way to only apply CSS-declaration to children, so I can **design a website by its structure**.

I already tried

```
header article {
  css-declaration;
}
```

and

```
header.article {
  css-declaration;
}
```

but these didn't work.
I also did some research, but I didn't find anything.

An example Code:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h>Title</h>
  </header>

  <article>
    <header>
      <h>Article Title</h>
    </header>

    <section>
      <h>Section Title</h>
    </section>
  </article>
</body>
```

```
article header h {
  css-declaration;
}
```

As you can probably imagine, I only want to affect the `<h>` element (Article Title), which is located in a `<header>` within an `<article>`, but I don't want to affect the `<h>` element (Title) in a `<header>` element in the `<body>` element as well not the `<h>` element (Section Title) in the `<section>` element.

Comment: "*I already tried `header article`...and `header.article`...*" - you first need to learn about CSS selectors. Read "*[How CSS selectors work](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/)*."

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I found an article and I think this is what I searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To give a quick and easy answer:

use `article > header> h { css-declaration; }`.
This only selects all `<h>` elements, which has `<header>` as a parent, which has `<article>` as a parent.

## If you are further interested

As some persons already commented, the answer to my question is **selectors**.

For all the people, who also might struggle with the same question, I'm going to link some **documentation** of selectors. You can make some crazy stuff with these without using too many classes and ids. I would say, that it is a click worth (if you are not really familiar with CSS).

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [selfhtml](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Selektoren)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already in your question:

```
article header h {
  css-declaration;
}
```

This will only affect the  tags inside  and not the other  tags